# MessageBox in .net core 5

Tags: c#, .net-core

From what I read System.Windows.MessageBox is available in .net core 5
links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox?view=net-5.0

[Similar method to messageBox in .NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174614/similar-method-to-messagebox-in-net-core)

However when I try to use System.Windows.MessageBox I get the error:
The type or namespace name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'

Am I missing a setting?

Comment: You need to add reference to WPF with `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` in project file

Comment: Thanks @jl0pd. I also had to add <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy `net5.0` is the cross-platform runtime, equivalent to .NET Standard. To use Windows desktop features you need to target the Windows runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to use WPF, your `csproj` file has to look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF> <!-- this adds support for the GUI stuff like MessageBox -->
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then you should be able to do something like this in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace messagebox
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The most important part is `net5.0-windows`. Without it, no Desktop APIs can be used